# 'export'ing a variable in shell script

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables, variable

We have two scripts, `first.sh` and `second.sh`. We run `first.sh` from `second.sh` using the `.` (`source`) command.

I am stuck at this script,

first.sh

```
 value="myvalue"
 export value

 oldvalue="othervalue"
 export value
```

After initializing the value and exporting, we have initialized the oldvalue and again exported `value` instead of `oldvalue` , but still the `othervalue` is available in the script `second.sh`, even though we didn't export `oldvalue` in `first.sh`.

Comment: What other script? What about the environment (`declare -p oldvalue`) from which it is run?

Comment: @Laging...the value of variable is being used in another shellscript by using "oldvalue", so my doubt is 'though  we didn't export the oldvalue, how is it referencing it?

Comment: You should execute `declare -p oldvalue` in the shell from which the other script is run. In general: You can make environment variables available only to child processes. If you want some kind of independent inter-process communication you need a different mechanism e.g. a file which is written by one script and read by the other.

Comment: How are you running the other script? If you are using `.` or `source`, then that script is running in the same shell where `oldvalue` was set. Alternatively, it is possible that `oldvalue` was previously exported. Setting the value does not unexport it if done after the initial export.

Comment: the mechanism is the first.sh file have the above initialization i mentioned, and we are running the first.sh from second.sh using  "." command

Comment: If you're sourcing the second "script" with `.`, you're running the content of the second file in the same script, you're not running a separate script.

Comment: @Laging...here i'm trying to understand an old shell script, where the "oldvalue" is used in the second sh file where the first.sh is executed.

Comment: @AndyDalton...thanks

Comment: @HaukeLaging `declare: not found`, this is a shell question and a standard shell does not know about `declare`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sourcing the second "script" with `.`, you're running the content of the second file in the same script, you're not *running* a separate script.

Consider, for example, these two scripts where one *runs* the other:

```
$ ls
script1*    script2*

$ cat script1
#!/bin/bash

export value="myvalue"
oldvalue="othervalue"

# Here script1 is running the second script (not sourcing it)
./script2

$ cat script2
#!/bin/bash

echo "value: ${value}"
echo "oldvalue: ${oldvalue}"
```

Note here that `script1` sets and exports `value` and sets but does not export `oldvalue`, then runs `script2` as a separate process.  `script2`, in turn, tries to print both values.  Here's the output:

```
$ ./script1
value: myvalue
oldvalue:
```

As you can see, your expectation about the visibility of the two variables is correct in this case -- since `oldvalue` was not exported from `script1`, its value wasn't defined in `script2`.

Comment: In the question it says "**but still the othervalue is available in the another script**".

Comment: @HaukeLaging which it cannot be, as illustrated.  It's much easier to answer the question once the comments reveal the misunderstanding.

Comment: As you say: the comments. They do reveal that one "script" is sourced by "the other". Your answer describes a completely different situation.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Yes, my answer illustrates (1) how to actually run one script from another and (2) that the OP's expectation of the behavior is correct when doing so.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that effectively you do not have two scripts but one script which is spread over two files like an `include` in other programming languages.

Thus the variable is not passed via the environment between the two script parts, it is available because it is part of the same shell process.

This works only because you run

```
. first.sh
```

before you access the variable. So this would work in `second.sh`

```
. first.sh
echo "$oldvalue"
```

but this would not

```
echo "$oldvalue"
. first.sh
```